# Redrawing silverlight accordion item not working

Tags: silverlight, xaml, accordion

I have a datagrid in an accordion that I programmatically add items to.  The items don't have a problem being added, but the accordion item doesn't refresh to a size that can view all the contents of the datagrid.  If I drag the datagrids sides to resize it, the accordion item resizes correctly.  I can't seem to do this automatically through code.  I have tried InvalidateArrage and InvalidateMeasure on the grid or the accordion item and I've also tried changing the widths or heights of the controls, but nothing seems to work through code.  I've even tried the Invalidate methods on the LayoutRoot.  Is there anything I can do code wise to make the accordion item refresh to the proper size?

Comment: I have been dealing with the same issue with an `ItemsControl` for a long time. I swear I have tried everything. I surely hope this gets answered.

Comment: Any chance you can post some xaml that recreates the problem?

Comment: +1 to Jason... You really do need to provide your XAML for problems like this one. Otherwise we have to guess where you might be going wrong :)

Comment: i'll get you an answer for this tomorrow @ work

Comment: Adding Items to code is really not correct way, you should use binding and try doing some MVVM stuff, Silverlight works best with binding without any layout issues ever !!

Comment: @Akash : "without any layout issues ever" is totally false.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, but with ListBox in AccordionItem. I solve this - put your DataGrid in Grid control

```
<toolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>

                      <DataGrid.../>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
```

And you need to call UpdateLayout() method when you ItemsSource is changed (item added)

```
   private void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                yourAccordion.UpdateLayout();
            }
```